# how to show result of google search api in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, google-api

I use google search api for my web application.
I don't know how to show the result of search in a `Gridview`.
I don't know how to show search obj into a `Gridview`... 
When I use `gridview.datasource=search`, there is an exception.

Here is my code:

```
    const string apiKey = "my key";
    const string searchEngineId = "my search engin id";
     string query = TextBox1.Text;// the query for search
    CustomsearchService customSearchService = new CustomsearchService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = apiKey });
    Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(query);
    listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId;
    Search search= listRequest.Execute();
  //************** bellow code have error**********      
   // GridView2.DataSource = listRequest.Execute();
  //  GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Show code of `Search` class ? Also you need to bind `list` or `array` to gridview.

Comment: i don't implement search class myself but I use Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1

using Google;
using Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1;
using Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

Comment: for console project i can use this code

            foreach (var item in search.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Title : " + item.Title + Environment.NewLine + "Link : " + item.Link + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

but for gridview i don't know

Comment: Try this `GridView2.DataSource = Search.Items`.`GridView2.DataBind();`

Comment: yessss, that's right
thank you so much

Comment: OK i am posting the answer please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind GridView with an `array` or `List`. Your `Search` class contains a property `Items` which is `collection` so you need to bind `gridview` with it.

```
GridView2.DataSource = Search.Items;
GridView2.DataBind();
```